# systemctl get-default differs from default.target link

Tags: systemd

The default target returned by systemctl

```
[user@host system]$ systemctl get-default
multi-user.target
```

differs from the value of the /usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target link:

```
[user@host system]$ ls -l /usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Mar 10 21:20 /usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target -> graphical.target
```

My understanding was that these were one and the same. If systemd doesn't store the default value as the default.target symlink, where is the real value of the default target stored by systemd?

Comment: Did you check `/etc/systemd/system/` for an alternate `default.target`? It might be pointing to `multi-user.target` in there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most likely because `/etc/systemd/system/default.target` exists and points to `multi-user.target`

If you change the `default.target` with `systemctl set-default [unit]`, the new `default.target` link is created in `/etc/systemd/system/`. The existing `/usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target` is not changed when using the `set-default` command. Like with all systemd units, the ones in `/etc` take precedence over `/usr`.

Answer (score 4):

[systemd FAQ](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/) on "*How do I change the default runlevel to boot into?*":

> The symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target controls where we boot into by default.

When default target isn't configured, the default one in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/default.target` is used.